# Reverse for 'completetodo' with arguments '(None,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['todo/(?P<todo_pk>[0-9]+)/complete$'] Django

Tags: django, reverse

i'm trying to do a function that calls a detail from a object.

The URL:

```
path('todo/<int:todo_pk>/complete', views.completetodo, name='completetodo'),
path('todo/<int:todo_pk>', views.viewtodo, name="viewtodo"),
```

The viewtodo receive the request with the GET method to build the form and receive some changes on data. The view completetodo, should be a button to full a field that has finish data:

```
def viewtodo(request, todo_pk):
    todo = get_object_or_404(Todo, pk=todo_pk, user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'GET' :
        form = TodoForm (instance=todo)
        return render (request, 'TodoList/viewtodo.html', {'todo':Todo, 'form':form})

    if request.method == 'POST' :
        try:
            form = TodoForm(request.POST, instance= todo)
            form.save()
            return redirect('currentTodo')
        except ValueError:
            return render(request, 'TodoList/viewTodo.html', {'todo':Todo, 'form':form, 'error':'Houve um erro com os dados que tentou salvar. Por favor, tente novamente.'})

def completetodo(request, todo_pk):
    todo = get_object_or_404(Todo, pk=todo_pk, user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return render (request, 'TodoList/viewtodo.html')
```

The HTML:

```
{% extends 'TodoList/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {{ error }}
    {{ todo.title }}
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit"> Alterar </button>
    </form>

    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'completetodo' todo.id %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit">Concluir</button>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing variable in context

```
def completetodo(request, todo_pk):
    todo = get_object_or_404(Todo, pk=todo_pk, user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return render (request, 'TodoList/viewtodo.html', {'todo':todo})
```

Also you are using variable in template that does not exist "Todos", and iterating multiple objects in place where only single object is queried ( which was not even passed to context, now accessible as todo)

You should look up into intro [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/)

Comment: Tks for the answer..... I put the wrong HTML here..... I'm replacing now.